# Why do probabilities have to be small in poisson distribution?

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

Why do the event of interests have to be rare when using the poisson distribtution?

small p and n*p < roughly 7 are required according to our book without explaining why.

We went through the proof of deriving the poisson distribution from the binomial distribution as n approaches infinity but a need for n and p didn't come up anywhere.

Comment: The point is that $np$ approaches a number that is neither $0$ nor $\infty$ as $n\to\infty.$ Necessarily that means $p\to0. \qquad$

Answer (score 0):

You wrote, "We went through the proof of deriving the Poisson distribution from the binomial distribution as n approaches infinity."  Consider what happens when $n$ and $p$ are fixed and don't satisfy these requirements.

For example, if $n=4$ and $p=1/4$ in a binomial distribution, then $P(X=0)=(3/4)^4=81/256$.  Now, compare this to $P(X=0)$ for a Poisson distribution with $\mu=1$.  They aren't very close.  This isn't in disagreement the proof that you went over, because that proof tells you what happens *in the limit as $n$ goes to infinity*.